# The symbolic meaning of the colour green in islam

Tags: prophets

Why is the colour green connected with islam? Why Al-Khidr was callled "The green One"? Why favourite colour of prophet Mohamed was the colour green?

Comment: What is the evidence for al-Khidr meaning the green one?

Answer (score 1):

Green serves as a recurring color-theme throughout the Quran. It's the color of many items in Heaven (cushions, clothes, gardens, etc) It's the color used in reference to the restored earth after being dead and so on. As for the Prophet (PBUH), he wore many green garments, saw the vision of Aisha (RA) wrapped in green, and so on.

It's also important to note, that for Arabs of the time who were living in dry dead deserted areas around Arabia, the Green Color serves as a symbol of life, hope, desire, etc.

Some verses and Ahadith:

- > Reclining on green cushions and beautiful carpets. **(55:76)**
- > Sent down rain from the sky and the earth becomes green? Indeed, Allah is Subtle and Acquainted. **(22:63)**
- > Two Gardens, dark green and fresh **(55:64)**
- > *It was narrated that Abu Rimthah said: "I saw the Prophet (ﷺ) delivering the Khutbah, wearing two green Burds."* ( Jami`
  >         at-Tirmidhi, Chapters on Manners )
- > *Narrated 'Aishah: that Jibril came to the Prophet (ﷺ) with her image
  >   upon a piece of green silk cloth, and he said: "This is your wife in
  >   the world, and in the Hereafter."*  (Jami` at-Tirmidhi, Chapters on Virtues)

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic meaning of green in Islam
This color in Islamic thought is also a symbol of heaven and heavenly beings, prophets and imams; And in mysticism and Sufism as a stage of mystical behavior. Nature, faith, wisdom, youth and vitality, etc. are other symbols of green. (1)
Green is the most beautiful color that has been mentioned ten times in the Qur'an and in a few verses it refers to the garments of the heavenly beings and their silk clothes and green silks. The color of green plants has also been repeated several times in the Qur'an. Green is a transmitter of happiness, expansion of mind and happiness. It is a symbol of growth, life and life.

Green is a symbol of faith, perfection and the color of heaven, and because it is evident in the color green of faith and confidence, it is considered a sacred color by Muslims, and people establish a connection between this color and the Holy Prophet and the Ahl al-Bayt and their descendants.
Green in the culture of the Qur'an is the color of heaven and heavenly beings. The Qur'an beautifully depicts the green of heavenly garments and carpets and the covers on their backs. Paradise is a place of eternity and a place of rest and tranquility, so this tranquility is provided for them in every way; Even in the kind of colors used in heaven. That is why the color of heaven, the clothes and the bed of heaven are green. (2)

(1)Ref: https://paykareh.scu.ac.ir/article_15725.html
(2)Ref: https://mehad.org/Pages.aspx?pid=87